# How to add translator to CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, translators

I am using `CKEditor` in my `rails 5 application`. I would like to have a support of Internationalizationin my CKEditor means I will select language and when I am typing content should change to that language. Is it possible to add this feature to my CKEditor. Please tell me the possibilities on how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Internationalization is not translation. I18n is formatting of dates, currencies etc. What you are talking is a full-scale translation. It will require , for example, usage of third party apps, like Google Translate or similar. This can be done using JS, but it will be a comples feature.

Comment: @DenisRomanovsky I can use JS. Could you please tell me how to approach this

Answer (score 0):

As a proof of concept, you can try two approaches:

1. If you need translation on the fly, you will need to use third party services with a JS made requests.
   You`ll have to learn the API of ,for example, Bing translation service. And add some JS to send the text to it and replace the CKEditor content with the result.
2. You can also translate on server side using gems like [this](https://github.com/relrod/bing_translator-gem). So you can push text from ckeditor to your own backoffice, utilize the gem to send it to API. And render the form with the result.

Comment: Thank you denis for your answer. I don't want to use any third party API's but instead I heard like we can achieve this using character encoding but don't have complete idea. Can you please share your views  on how to use character encoding if you have any idea